# update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet util-linux (--configure) :

Tags: dpkg

i try to install upgrade or some packages and i receive the error

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
 update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet util-linux (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me, I'm using ubuntu 14.10 .. Thanks

Comment: Is it a clean installation?

Comment: Yes , I guess it's clean

Comment: I think `util-linux` init script in /etc/init.d  is missing LSB information

Comment: And what can i do to fix this problem

Answer (score 6):

I think `util-linux` init script in /etc/init.d is missing LSB information

As a temporary workaround you can locate that script and add something like at top

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          
# Required-Start:    
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: 
### END INIT INFO
```

But it's not a complete solution. You will keep getting such error messages whenever you install an application that adds init script into /etc/init.d

I had similar problem and I fixed it with applying the solution in the last post on this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/insserv/+bug/467000

**Note that it doesn't mean it will work in your case. And It might break your system**

For LSB information check out https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Comment: I will see if it's run in my case and i will tell you , thank u very much

Comment: please be careful

Comment: I try this solution but nothing new , still the same problem

Comment: Did you add repo aside from Ubuntu?

Comment: I don t understand , I m not a pro

Comment: You most probably added another repository apart from official ubuntu repositories.  Your main repositories are in `/etc/apt/sources.list` To check out all of your repositories run `software-properties-gtk`

Comment: You can see your official repository content by `cat  /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I will try if it run or not

Answer (score 0):

If you paste more info, it'll be helpful. I came this issue when I install anything.

Here is the issue,

> ```
> Extracting templates from packages: 100%
> Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.5) ...
> insserv: warning: script 'S15solrd' missing LSB tags and overrides
> insserv: warning: script 'solrd' missing LSB tags and overrides
> insserv: Starting solrd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
> insserv: Starting solrd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
> insserv: Starting solrd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
> insserv: Starting solrd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
> insserv: Starting solrd depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
> insserv: There is a loop between service solrd and rc.local if started
> insserv:  loop involving service rc.local at depth 12
> insserv:  loop involving service solrd at depth 1
> insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
> update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
> dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
>  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>  util-linux
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ```

From the output I guess I didn't config solrd right. So I remove all the thing relate to solrd in rc.local or rc